# What is the use of Get trait here?

Tags: pallet, rust, referenda

In the referenda pallet, type Tracks uses two trait, Get and TracksInfo

[substrate/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs#L226)

```rust
/// Information concerning the different referendum tracks.
        #[pallet::constant]
        type Tracks: Get<
                Vec<(
                    <Self::Tracks as TracksInfo<BalanceOf<Self, I>, BlockNumberFor<Self>>>::Id,
                    TrackInfo<BalanceOf<Self, I>, BlockNumberFor<Self>>,
                )>, // Vec contains Id and TrackInfo
            > + TracksInfo<
                BalanceOf<Self, I>,
                BlockNumberFor<Self>,
                RuntimeOrigin = <Self::RuntimeOrigin as OriginTrait>::PalletsOrigin,
            >;
```

TracksInfo trait functions is accessed as:

```rust
let track = T::Tracks::track_for(&proposal_origin).map_err(|_| Error::<T, I>::NoTrack)?;
```

```rust
/// Information on the voting tracks.
pub trait TracksInfo<Balance, Moment> {
    /// The identifier for a track.
    type Id: Copy + Parameter + Ord + PartialOrd + Send + Sync + 'static + MaxEncodedLen;

    /// The origin type from which a track is implied.
    type RuntimeOrigin;

    /// Return the array of known tracks and their information.
    fn tracks() -> &'static [(Self::Id, TrackInfo<Balance, Moment>)];

    ///  Determine the voting track for the given `origin`.
    fn track_for(origin: &Self::RuntimeOrigin) -> Result<Self::Id, ()>;

    /// Return the track info for track `id`, by default this just looks it up in `Self::tracks()`.
    fn info(id: Self::Id) -> Option<&'static TrackInfo<Balance, Moment>> {
        Self::tracks().iter().find(|x| x.0 == id).map(|x| &x.1)
    }
}
```

What's the use of Get trait? How its used?

Answer (score 0):

I currently find it useless. `TracksInfo` could offer more detailed data. `TracksInfo::tracks` could replace the `Get::get` here.

Moreover, I searched several repositories but found no instances where `Get` was used for any special cases.

I believe this could be a "mistake" made during the development process.